# Facebook API trouble

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I am just starting off with Facebook for Android. I have followed the instructions provided on the developer website. I created a facebook project and used Android 2.3.3 as target. Then I created another project(with the same target) and added the Facebook project. However, the following error keeps popping up: "Unable to resolve target 'android-3'". I have the APKs 7 and 10 only. How do I resolve this? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest file change target sdk version to 10. That might look like this.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" 
      android:targetSdkVersion="10"
       />
```

Answer (score 0):

in http://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/

> You'll need to have the Android 2.2 (API 8) components installed in
>   order to use the Facebook SDK.